# Express session authentification and assigning variables

Tags: node.js, authentication, express-session, nedb

I am facing weird issue. I believe its very simple to experienced people.

Making local web server on Node.js+Express+NeDB

Client on login makes POST request to `/login` form and is redirected on successful login.
`{"id":1,"created":1568146217901,"username":"sprice","name":"Steve Price","email":"email@gmail.com","password":"Password","level":"1","_id":"3JDE7p6tAl1vD11k"}`
Login post

```
// POST services
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const loginData = req.body;
    db.users.findOne({ username: loginData.uname }, function (err, doc) {
        req.session.userId = doc.id;
        if(doc.id === 1) console.log("True"); // < Output: True
        console.log(req.session.userId); // < Output: 1
    });
    req.session.userId = 1; // < Just for test
    res.redirect('/plan');
});
```

Before going into `/plan` page there is an auth check:

```
const redirectLogin = (req, res, next) => {
    const { userId } = req.session;
    console.log(userId); // < Output: undefined
    if (!userId) {
        res.render('pages/index');
    } else {
        next()
    }
}
```

So my weird question, if i assign value from DB which is integer and to test that i have if statement i get `req.session.userId = 1`, but when client is redirected its `req.session.userId = undefined`.
But if i assign value manually with that test line it works and server issues cookie and i can visit my site with no problems...
Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the fact that the callback to `.findOne()` is ***asynchronous*** and ***non-blocking***.  That means that your request handler returns first and THEN, sometime later (after the `res.redirect()` has already been sent), the callback gets called.  So, the callback is too late for the redirect.  Instead, you need to do the `res.redirect()` inside the callback:

```
// POST services
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const loginData = req.body;
    db.users.findOne({ username: loginData.uname }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }
        req.session.userId = doc.id;
        if(doc.id === 1) console.log("True"); // < Output: True
        console.log(req.session.userId); // < Output: 1
        res.redirect('/plan');
    });
});
```

Depending upon what session store you're using, you may also have to save any changes to your session before you redirect.

Comment: gotha, i was thinking i has to do something to asynchronous stuff... Thank you sir